# Why a 404 on every available page on a Web Site project?

Tags: asp.net, vs-web-site-project

I've just opened a Web Site project found on my predecessor's machine and - I hate the things and don't ever work with them - I get a 404 on every link I click, while the page is definitely present. If I directly view the individual page in the browser, that page works fine, except for any links on it to other pages.

It's like the built-in dev web server isn't operating and interpreting URL requests, but I have no idea where to look to clear this up.

**USING IIS:** If I create and deploy this site under IIS, everything seems to work normally.

**MY MAIN QUESTION IS:** *Why do pages get not get served on this site and do get served on similar sites, under debugging a Web Site project on VS2012. It is not how to solve the problem by deploying to IIS.*

Comment: Look like you want us to wild guess the problem :). Well the first thing is use fiddler to see what request you are sending and getting reply from it. Also try to make a link to HTML file and see if that works.

Comment: I don't want you to wild guess the problem. Web sites normally behave well under Visual Studio debugging, and this one doesn't. I was hoping someone had experienced a similar problem. I have added some more info.

Comment: Why don't you map your application folder with a virtual directory?

Comment: Since under IIS it works fine, I suggest try to create a new Solution file, hope that is not a big task and solve your problem. I prefer to use VS inbuilt IIS Express over system IIS, I know it has lot of problems specially when you work on multiple machines.

Comment: If it is a Web Site project it probably has a Virtual Path set in the Developer Web Server properties.